# How to create cumulative bins in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df which looks like this:

```
date       | user_id | purchase_probability | sales
2020-01-01 | 1       | 0.19                 | 10
2020-01-20 | 1       | 0.04                 | 0
2020-01-01 | 3       | 0.31                 | 5
2020-01-10 | 2       | 0.05                 | 18
```

How can I best create a new dataframe that creates cumulative buckets in 10% increments such as:

```
probability_bin | total_users | total_sales 
0-10%           | 2           | 18+0=18
0-20%           | 2           | 18+0+10=28
0-30%           | 2           | 28     
0-40%           | 3           | 10+0+5+18=33
0-50%           | 3           | 33
0-60%           | same for all rows below
0-70%
0-80%
0-90%
0-100%
```

I tried using a custom function and also pandas pcut and qcut but not sure how to get to that cumulative output.
Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cut` to create normal bins, then aggregate and cumsum:

```
bins = np.arange(0, 101, 10)
labels = [f'0-{int(i)}%' for i in bins[1:]]

group = pd.cut(df['purchase_probability'], bins=bins/100, labels=labels)

(df.groupby(group)
   .agg(total_users=('user_id', 'count'), total_sales=('sales', 'sum'))
   .cumsum()
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am not sure if the probability_bin index looks right. Your outputs 0-10, 10-20,20-30 when i was looking for 0-10, 0-20, 0-30 etc. Is that just the labelling of those or is the calc also not aligned?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input as DataFrame constructor? Yes the labels are incorrect but the values are correct. For 5% use 0.05 in place of 0.1 in `arange`.

Comment: I just did a test and the users are not cumulatively adding up from 0-X%. Could you double check the solution please?

Comment: I can if you provide a DataFrame constructor (I'm on my phone)